# Git won't stop tracking eclipse java .recommenders

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-luna

I haven't had this problem before Eclipse Luna (I updated from Kepler just few days ago).
Although I added to .recommenders to .gitignore it keeps tracking it.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .recommenders/caches/identified-project-coordinates.json
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.fdt
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.fdx
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.fnm
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.frq
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.nrm
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.prx
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.tii
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_3.tis
        modified:   .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/segments.gen
        deleted:    .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/segments_4
        modified:   .recommenders/repository/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/org/ecli
.properties

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.fdt
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.fdx
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.fnm
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.frq
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.nrm
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.prx
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.tii
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/_5.tis
        .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_luna_/segments_6

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
*target*
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.class

# eclipse specific git ignore
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath
.recommenders/

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch
```

If I do git rm -rf --cached it removes it, but soon starts tracking again - as soon as my colleague makes changes in his files and push it on Bitbucket and I do pull.
**How should I fix this problem permanently?**

Also, when I just did "git rm -r --cached .recommenders" it deleted whole bunch of cached files but top level directory stays.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .recommenders/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If I try to remove it then it completely resets Eclipse workspace, and I have to import all projects all over again (so it doesn't physically delete workspace".

Comment: Doing `git rm --cached` is the right thing to do, but all of your colleagues should do it as well... Otherwise you'll keep having this problem

Comment: @fge Yes, but what puzzles me is that all of us did it, and problem still pop out after a while?

Comment: @fge Also, when I just did "git rm -r --cached .recommenders" it deleted whole bunch of cached files but top level directory stays. 

"$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .recommenders/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)"



If I try to remove it then it completely resets Eclipse workspace, and I have to import all projects all over again (so it doesn't physically delete workspace".

Comment: I don't get it, `--cached` is supposed to leave the files in there; did you commit after that?

Comment: @fge Yes, perhaps I should check tomorrow settings on other workstations, maybe something is missing

Comment: @fge As it turned out, on one workstation there was missing ".recommenders/" in ".gitignore" file. You pointed me in right direction, so if you want, expand your comment with checking for this besides doing "git rm -rf --cached" on all workstations and I will accept your answer.

Comment: I didn't really mention the .gitignore, did I? ;) That's OK, the essential thing is that you eventually solved your problem! Have fun ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turned out, on one workstation there was missing

```
.recommenders/
```

in .gitignore file on one workstation. 
Adding that as well as running

```
git rm -rf --cached
```

on every workstation solved the problem.

Comment: That will remove all cached files. I believe would be less harmful to do this: `git rm -r --cached .recommenders/**/*`